# Ansible: How to combine list of dictionaries?

Tags: list, dictionary, merge, ansible

I need help with merging List of Dictionaries. Below is a sample data of 2 dictionaries. I have tried several methods. The below json shows the sample input. While the only element that changes is the Host in the entire list of Dictionaries. I need to combine the data into a single list of dictionary to post an API call. And it is not always there will be only 4 Dictionaries part of the list.

Basically looking to group / merge the data such that the common details does not change and only new details get appended.

**Input**

```json
[
        {
            "Batch_number": "Batch1",
            "Date": "20221228",
            "Host": "Host1",
            "Job_Template_ID": 7,
            "Patch_Cycle": 30,
            "Patch_Day": "Day1",
            "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
            "Recurrency": "Once",
            "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
            "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
            "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
        },
        {
            "Batch_number": "Batch1",
            "Date": "20221230",
            "Host": "Host11",
            "Job_Template_ID": 7,
            "Patch_Cycle": 30,
            "Patch_Day": "Day2",
            "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
            "Recurrency": "Once",
            "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
            "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
            "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
        },
        {
            "Batch_number": "Batch1",
            "Date": "20230101",
            "Host": "Host21",
            "Job_Template_ID": 7,
            "Patch_Cycle": 30,
            "Patch_Day": "Day3",
            "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
            "Recurrency": "Once",
            "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
            "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
            "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
        },
        {
            "Batch_number": "Batch1",
            "Date": "20230103",
            "Host": "Host31",
            "Job_Template_ID": 7,
            "Patch_Cycle": 30,
            "Patch_Day": "Day4",
            "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
            "Recurrency": "Once",
            "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
            "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
            "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
        }
    ]
```

**Expected Output**

```json
{
            "Batch_number": "Batch1",
            "Date": "20230103",
            "Host": ["Host1","Host11","Host21","Host31"],
            "Job_Template_ID": 7,
            "Patch_Cycle": 30,
            "Patch_Day": "Day4",
            "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
            "Recurrency": "Once",
            "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
            "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
            "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"}
```

Comment: Can you provide a description for your question? Since Input and Output are given, can you provide more information regarding your current processing step? Isn't this covered by [Merging lists of dictionaries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_merging_lists_of_dictionaries.html)?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @Zeitounator - I have added more details on this question. could you please help. I am unable to find a proper method for this

Comment: Regarding "_I have tried several methods_", can you edit your question again and provide details about what have you tried and where are you stuck, which method you have used and what was the result? Also, where you able to have a look into the given documentation?

Comment: Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. Users are expected to show an honest try to solve their problem, not just a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve expected output by simple `combine` filters.

Test playbook below

```yaml
---
- name: Combine batches
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:

    batches: >-
      [
              {
                  "Batch_number": "Batch1",
                  "Date": "20221228",
                  "Host": "Host1",
                  "Job_Template_ID": 7,
                  "Patch_Cycle": 30,
                  "Patch_Day": "Day1",
                  "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
                  "Recurrency": "Once",
                  "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
                  "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
                  "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
              },
              {
                  "Batch_number": "Batch1",
                  "Date": "20221230",
                  "Host": "Host11",
                  "Job_Template_ID": 7,
                  "Patch_Cycle": 30,
                  "Patch_Day": "Day2",
                  "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
                  "Recurrency": "Once",
                  "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
                  "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
                  "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
              },
              {
                  "Batch_number": "Batch1",
                  "Date": "20230101",
                  "Host": "Host21",
                  "Job_Template_ID": 7,
                  "Patch_Cycle": 30,
                  "Patch_Day": "Day3",
                  "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
                  "Recurrency": "Once",
                  "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
                  "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
                  "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
              },
              {
                  "Batch_number": "Batch1",
                  "Date": "20230103",
                  "Host": "Host31",
                  "Job_Template_ID": 7,
                  "Patch_Cycle": 30,
                  "Patch_Day": "Day4",
                  "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
                  "Recurrency": "Once",
                  "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
                  "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
                  "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
              }
          ]

  tasks:

    - name: Show combined batch
      debug:
        var: batches | from_json | combine | combine({'Host':batch_hosts}) | to_nice_json
      vars:
        batch_hosts: >-
          {{ batches | from_json | map(attribute='Host') }}
```

giving the expected result

```yaml
TASK [Show combined batch] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  batches | from_json | combine | combine({'Host':batch_hosts}) | to_nice_json: |-
    {
        "Batch_number": "Batch1",
        "Date": "20230103",
        "Host": [
            "Host1",
            "Host11",
            "Host21",
            "Host31"
        ],
        "Job_Template_ID": 7,
        "Patch_Cycle": 30,
        "Patch_Day": "Day4",
        "RRule": "INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1;FREQ=MINUTELY",
        "Recurrency": "Once",
        "Start_Time": "17:00:00",
        "Technical_Tower": "Unix",
        "Timezone": "Asia/Culcutta"
    }
```